# What is the current through this parallel circuit?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, resistance

[image]I'm trying to solve the attached circuit for I1 and I2. I think I1 is just 5A but I'm not so sure about I2, I think it might be just 10/5=2A but I'm not sure if the voltage in the top right part is still equal to 10V or not.

I'm new to electronics, thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't \$R_2\$ shorted by the wiring? Or am I missing something?

Comment: But don't you need to go from + to - without passing a resistor for that?

Comment: what is the voltage across R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at both sides of \$R_2\$ and compare the voltage difference, and then make a conclusion based on Ohm's Law about the current.

Also, this is **not** a parallel circuit. Parallel components MUST share BOTH nodes.

Comment: thanks, is the voltage difference just 10 volts?

Comment: No. What's the voltage on one side of the resistor? What's the voltage on the other side of the resistor? What's the difference between the two voltages? (Hint: they're connected together, and all wires that are connected share a common voltage)

Comment: so on one side it's 10V and same goes for the other side, so potential difference is 0V, so no current in the top right part? Is that right?

Comment: Yeah that's right. When working on problems on this and determining currents/voltages, I always look at the components individually to see if I can figure out what's going on before looking at the overall circuit. Then, once all the basics are done and I'm still missing what I want, then I continue to KVL / KCL.